# How to create an HTML bookmark anchor for a JavaScript tab

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a seemingly simple problem to which I wasn't able to find a solution today. How can I create a bookmark (i.e., example.com/somepage**#mybookmark**) which automatically opens up elements under a JavaScript tab, such as the tabs suggested for use on [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_tabs.asp)?

I've tried assigning some `id`s to the `<li>` elements forming the tabs, e.g:

```
<li id="mybookmark"><a href="#" class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'London')">London</a></li>
```

and even an anchor name, e.g:

```
<li><a name="mybookmark" href="#" class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'London')">London</a></li>
```

but the best result I got so far when trying example.com/somepage#mybookmark was only to highlight the tab, without opening the content associated to it (which is what I actually want).

I presume that the answer lies in some JavaScript code, but could someone suggest how it should look?

Comment: You will need to read the URL hash on page load, and run the appropriate JS.

Comment: Try Bootstrap tabs, tutorial is here ---> http://www.tutorialrepublic.com/twitter-bootstrap-tutorial/bootstrap-tabs.php

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
$(function () {
    $(".tab-content").hide().first().show();
    $(".yourNav li:first").addClass("active");

    $(".yourNav a").on('click', function (e) { 
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).closest('li').addClass("active").siblings().removeClass("active");
    $($(this).attr('href')).show().siblings('.tab-content').hide();
});

    var hash = $.trim( window.location.hash );
    if (hash) $('.inner-nav a[href$="'+ hash + '"]').trigger('click');
});
```

Basically you would be forcing the `.click()` of the tab based on the url form the `#` on. The top portion of this you said you already have, i.e. tabs opening fine and all that, its the second part where the `var hash =` is declared. Let me know and good luck.

Comment: Thanks for answering. Unfortunately, I cannot get it to work, though I understand the principle of forcing the tab to be clicked if the request has a #. Here is my JS function, which works just fine (but doesn't show the content of the tabs if tab is requested as a bookmark, of course): http://pastebin.com/wwj5eSJj Any thoughts?